# где как и кто описывает операторы и разные другие коды (c++)

Tags: c++, c

Здраствуйте я занимаюсь программированием на c++ и я хотел спросить, я постоянно пользуюсь всякими словами операторами и тд
пример: using,int,float,ios_base::trunc и тд (заметьте библиотек для этого подключать не надо) так вот где же описывается эти все операторы и все такое(то что нет в библиотеках)

Comment: `ios_base::trunc` как раз берется из библиотек, а все встроенные языковые типы и конструкции описываются в стандарте ну и на всяких справочных сайтах, типа cppreference.com

Comment: [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2e6a4at9.aspx)

Comment: но лучше всего искать в стандарте с++: [тут](https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard) на английском языке официальный стандарт комитета по стандартизации с++, существует перевод на русский язык стандарта c++17 Евгения Зуева (Приложение А: служебные слова)

Comment: Именно по этому начинающим лучше использовать Visual Studio. Каждое слово которое не покрашено в синий цвет имеет ссылку на документ в котором оно описано. Наводим курсор, нажимаем F12, открывается документ.

Comment: то чего не надо подключать описано в самом коде компилятора

Comment: Коротко и ясно:
https://ru.cppreference.com/w/

Answer (score 6):

using,int,float - ключевые слова, встроенные в язык программирования С++. Когда вы пишете код на каком-либо языке, то получается просто текст - набор символов. Бесполезный, если нет какой-либо программы, которая могла бы интепретировать этот текст, как его "осмысливать", преобразовывать в то, что было бы понятно компьютеру. Эта программа называется компилятором. Она преобразует текст, написанный на данном языке программирования, в машинные инструкции (которые понятны компьютеру), либо в другой формат.

Коротко говоря, эти ключевые слова - это средства языка, с помощью которого можно писать программы на данном языке. По сути эти средства в совокупности с синтаксисом и семантикой всяких конструкций и определяют конкретный язык (определение возможно неточное, но надеюсь донесёт суть).

*
Пример использования:
Ключевые слова типа int, float нужны компилятору, чтобы знать тип объявленной переменной или параметра в функцию. Когда компилятор С++ увидит в тексте объявление переменной такого типа, он поймёт, что нужно выделить на стеке память под эту переменную. И все операции, которые будут проводиться с этой переменной (сложение, умножение, запись, чтение и т.д.) должны быть операциями конкретно для данного типа. В процессоре команды для работы с целыми числами и вещественными - разные. Но чтобы в коде не писать два разных типа '+_int' и '+_float', разработчики языка дали возможность вам не задумываться над тем, какой плюс ставить, тем самым возлагая ответственность за это на компилятор, так как это рутинная работа и её можно сделать автоматически исходя из типа переменной. Т.е. вы указываете тип переменной один раз, а дальше компилятор сам будет понимать, какую конкретно операцию для этой переменной нужно использовать. Это называется более высокий уровень абстракции - когда избавляются от несущественных вещей (выбора конкретной операции для конкретной переменной), оставляя программисту возможность работать с существенными вещами (с теми, где компилятору уже труднее справиться или невозможно, например, выбор алгоритма и т.п.).

P.S. Отвечая на сам вопрос о местоположении описания операторов: в коде самого компилятора.

Comment: Ну а где все таки это все описанно? все команды  using,int,float в самой среде разработке?

Comment: Нет, не в среде разработки. Среда разработки нужна для удобного кодинга. Написанная программа не зависит от того, в какой среде она написана. Вы можете в блокноте её написать и потом через консоль скомпилировать. Суть в компиляторе, который и распознаёт язык, в том числе средства языка. Например, using, float, int и т.д.

Comment: В исходных кодах компилятора - если в двух словах :)